# FFImageLoading Terms And Condition

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is FFImageLoading Open Source or if i am using it then will it use my personal data?

**This is my code for image loading:**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackFrontImage" Padding="0" HeightRequest="100" Spacing="0" Margin="10" IsVisible="True">
                <ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage HeightRequest="100"
                                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                           VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                           Aspect="AspectFill" 
                                           x:Name="imageWave" 
                                           Source="outlet.gif"
                                           Margin="0"
                                           LoadingPlaceholder="imageWave1"
                                           Finish="ImageWave_Finish"
                                           DownloadStarted="ImageWave_DownloadStarted"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

Please tell me about it's Terms and Policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) is a Crossplatform XF library developed by [Daniel luberda](https://github.com/daniel-luberda) and [Fabien Molinet](https://github.com/molinch)

Now when you read their [License agreement](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/blob/master/LICENSE.md) you will note that they do not save any kind of personal data of any sort, also it is clearly mentioned that they are not liable for any issues you face while using their library

I hope this helps